# Discord.py BOT not messaging the user on join

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

I have been constantly trying to make my Discord BOT made with Python to DM a user whenever he joins my server. But the user is not getting the DM. I have tried several times with my different accounts but still nothing good. The source code is here:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import requests
import json
import random
import asyncio
import os
from keep_alive import keep_alive

intents=discord.Intents(members=True)
client=discord.Client(intents=intents)

welcomechannel=client.fetch_channel(857614545534189590)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("logged in as")
  print(client.user.name)
  print(client.user.id)
  print('-----')

newUserMessage = """
You
can
put
your
multiline
message
here!
"""
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  print("Recognised that a member called " + member.name + " joined")
  try:
    await client.send_message(member, newUserMessage)
    print("Sent message to " + member.name)
  except:
    print("Couldn't message " + member.name)
    embed=discord.Embed(
      title="Welcome "+member.name+"!", description="We're glad you are here!", color=discord.Color.green()
      )

@client.event
async def on_member_leave(member):
    print("Recognised that a member called " + member.name + " left")
    embed=discord.Embed(
        title=" Goodbye "+member.name+"!", description="Until we meet again", color=discord.Color.red() 
    )

keep_alive()
client.run(os.getenv('token'))
```

The BOT is running but unable to send DM to the user as I am getting the output in the console as:

```
logged in as
Test BOT (1)
857616712429994004
-----
Recognised that a member called xyz1234 joined
Couldn't message xyz1234
Recognised that a member called ksh_2605 joined
Couldn't message ksh_2605
```

Comment: `Couldn't message ksh_2605` is not helpful. We can't figure out anything from it and neither can you. How about printing the actual error you get? If @hexxx is correct, and this is about deprecated `send_message` method it would be immediately obvious from the the `AttributeError` saying something like `discort.Client has no attribute send_message` and you would have saved both your and our time.

Comment: @Kara Actually there is no error which prohibits the core from running. The code is executing but I am not getting the desired result. For example: If ksh_2605 is joining the server then he is not getting the personalized DM but the bot is running well. Should I share you the actual link of my code?

Answer (score 1):

client.send_message() is outdated.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_member_join#discord.Member

discord.Member has a method called send() so use that instead.